# Is this set a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

is this a subspace of R4?

1st criterion is fulfilled, because
(85,-58,11,0) is element of L5

But I dont know how to proof the 2nd and the 3rd

2nd says
λ element of R
a element of L5
a*λ element of L5

the 3rd says
a,b elements of L5 
a+b element of L5

**edit:**
all other criterions aside
would the 3rd aka a+b criterion be fulfilled?
a+b=(85,-58,11,0)+(85,-58,11,0)+(t1+t2)(-42,32,-7,1)

how to check if that term above is in L5?

Comment: *Hint*: Does $L_5$ contain a zero vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this was a subspace it would have to contain the zero vector. But this vector is not in $L_5$. You see this when you try to solve:
$$\begin{align}
85 - 42t &= 0 \\
-58 + 32t &= 0 \\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$
Since there is not value of $t$ satisfying all these equations, then zero vector is not in $L_5$.

Edit: Given the discussion in the comments below, it might  be that your definition of subspace doesn't directly require that the $0$ vector be an element of the space.

Let us say that the definition of a subspace $W$ of $V$ is simply that $W$ is a subset such that

1. For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $w\in W$, then $\lambda w \in W$
2. For $v,w\in W$, $v + w \in W$.

Now take any vector $v \in W$. Then $-1\cdot v = -v \in W$ by 1. Then $0 = v + (-v) \in W$ by 2. So indeed a subspace must contain the $0$ vector. As Jyrki points out in the comments below, you could also note that $0 \mathbb{R}$ so for any vector $v$ you get the zero vector by $0v$.

That said, in your concrete example, note that 
$$
\pmatrix{85 \\ -58 \\ 11 \\ 0} \in L_5.
$$
If $L_5$ was a subspace then
$$
2\pmatrix{85 \\ -58 \\ 11 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{170 \\ -116 \\ 22 \\ 0}
$$
would be an element in $L_5$. But again, when you try to solve
$$\begin{align}
85 - 42t &= 170 \\
-58 + 32t &= -116 \\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$
you find no solution.

Comment: I thought the first criterion says, L5 shall not be empty?

Comment: @user2147674: The first criterion might say that. And $L_5$ is indeed non-empty. But one of the requirements for a set to be a vector space is that it contain the zero vector. This is axiom three on this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition. Note that people number the conditions/requirements/axioms differently.

Comment: @user2147674: Is you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition_and_useful_characterization_of_subspace then the requirement that $0$ be in the subspace is number $1$.

Comment: I see, but in algebra class at university we have only noted that a subspace has to contain at least one element, a lambda*a is element of the subspace and a,b and a+b are elements of the subspace

Comment: @user2147674: As you see in the Wikipedia article that I linked to, it is in general required that $0$ be in any subspace as well. However, let me update my answer to show how $L_5$ also fails other requirements.

Comment: @user2147674: I updated my answer.

Comment: @user2147674: If you set $\lambda=0$ in that subspace criterion, then it follows, then you see that a subspace must contain the zero vector. It is sometimes easier to  (and logically sufficient) refute that consequence as opposed to on of the tests of the sucbspace criterion when proving that a set is not a subspace.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I will update my answer with what you said. I hope that's ok.